# Angular - ERROR TypeError: _co.timeIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, typeerror

I am using Angular, Express, Node.js, and MySQL to create a project. I made a button on the HTML that will call a function which will essentially insert the current time into my MySQL database and return the inserted time to the HTML. My function completely works the first time. Here is the code relevant to the problem:

**component.html:**

```
<tr *ngFor='let student of allStudents'>
            <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
            <td>{{student.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{student.last_name}}</td>
            <td *ngIf='!student.time_in'><input type="button" name="" (click)='timeIn(student.student_id)' value="">NULL</td>
            <td *ngIf='student.time_in'>{{student.time_in}}</td>
</tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
timeIn(val){
    val = {'val': val}
    return this._api.timeIn(val)
    .then(data => this.timeIn = data)
    .catch(errors => { console.log(errors)})
}
```

**service.ts**

```
timeIn(id){
    return this._http.post('/timeIn', id)
    .map(data => data.json())
    .toPromise();
}
```

**controller.js**

```
timeIn: function(req, res){
        connection.query('UPDATE students SET time_in = NOW() WHERE student_id = ' + req.body.val + ';', function(err, results, fields){
            if (err) console.log(err.message);
            connection.query('SELECT student_id, time_in FROM students WHERE student_id = ' + req.body.val + ';', function(err, results, fields){
                if (err) console.log(err.message);
                console.log(results);
                res.send(results);
            })
        })
    }
```

**Console.log(results)**

```
[ RowDataPacket { student_id: 45678, time_in: 2018-07-20T04:17:42.000Z } ]
```

As you can tell, multiple buttons are created for every student in the database. Each one has its own button with their unique student_id. However, after the first button click, it no longer works. The first time that **time_in()** is executed the current time is updated and returned. However, the function no longer works after. In the HTML console it returns this error:

```
StudentdashboardComponent.html:29 ERROR TypeError: _co.timeIn is not a function
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (StudentdashboardComponent.html:29)
at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
at core.js:10629
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
```

If I refresh the page, I can call the function again, but it doesn't work more than once per refresh. Does anyone know why it doesn't work after the second call? I couldn't find anything too specific to my problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in your component you have declared `timeIn` as a function and as a variable.

So because of that angular is getting confused if it is variable or function. Try changing you variable name.

What is  `this.timeIn = data` below??

```
timeIn(val){
    val = {'val': val}
    return this._api.timeIn(val)
    .then(data => this.timeIn = data) // what is this timeIn ??????
    .catch(errors => { console.log(errors)})
}
```

---

**Note:**

> I can call the function again, but it doesn't work more than once per
>   refresh

This is happen because in first time your  `timeIn` could identify as a function without any problem. But inside your `timeIn` function you are assigning a `data` come from `this._api.timeIn` to the `timeIn` in this case `timeIn` is no longer consider as a function but consider as a type of that `data` has. That's why you are getting **`timeIn is not a function`**. Use different variable to assign that `data`.

Thanks @coder for editing my answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so dumb after looking at this.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Accept my answer if it worked for you and up vote it :)

Comment: @EthanTom because of now you have an correct answer, I am adding this as **side note:** This is happen because in first time your  `timeIn` could identify as a function without any problem. But inside your `timeIn` function you are assigning a `data` come from `this._api.timeIn` to the `timeIn` in this case `timeIn` is no longer consider as a function type but consider as a type of that `data` has. That's why you are getting **`timeIn is not a function`**. that is why "Saurabh Agrawal" answer is working in your case.

Comment: @Saurabh Agrawal np. great ;)